# Swift get first instance of value inside array inside UITableView

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, cell

I have an array of models that each have a `id` which links to it's parent. I'm trying to get the first instance that this `id` appears inside the array and set a cell outlet property to false.

This array is used to populate a tableview and I'm currently using the tableView's Index to check. Trying to use the `.first()` approach but it's throwing an error:

> Cannot invoke 'first' with an argument list of type '(where: (Course) throws -> Bool)'

```
if courses.first(where: {$0.id == index}) {
    controller.courseTitleGroup.setHidden(true)
} else {
    controller.courseTitleGroup.setHidden(false)
}
```

The logic should be: **If the cell index == courses[index].id and its the first instance then return true**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify by doing

```
let found = courses.first(where: {$0.id == index}) != nil
controller.courseTitleGroup.setHidden(found)
```

You cannot do as you did because `first(where:)` return an optional `Course`, not a `Bool`; if statement allows only `Bool` values, so you can compare the optional return to be not nil.